# How can you make a form submit button add to a form method="Get" url?

Tags: php, forms

How can you add a Get request to a form button?  For example if you click the `[Landscape]` button how could you make it go to `print.php?Landscape` ?

```
 <form action="print.php" method="get">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" formaction="print.php?&type=Landscape" name="Landscape" value="Landscape"/>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" formaction="print.php?&type=Portrait" name="Portrait" value="Portrait"/>
 </form>
```

print.php

```
 <?PHP
 $Landscape= $_REQUEST['Landscape'];
  echo $Landscape;
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The name and value combined with `method="get"` will result with a `print.php?&Landscape=Landscape` .  This seems to be what you are asking for.

```
<form action="print.php" method="get">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Landscape" value="Landscape"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Portrait" value="Portrait"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form the form data will be expressed as a set of `name=value` pairs.

There is no way, in HTML, to generate a `name` without an `=value` by submitting a form.

The code you have already, since the submit button has a name and a value, will generate:

```
print.php?Landscape=Landscape
```

… which should be sufficient for all practical purposes.

---

That said, since you have no other controls, you can (and probably should) just use a link.

```
 <a href="print.php?Landscape" class="btn btn-default">Landscape</a>
```

Comment: So you can do a <a href="print.php?Landscape"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" formaction="print.php?&type=Landscape" ></a> ?

Comment: @Sol - No. Use a link instead of a button.

Comment: How would it pull in the form data or it can't?

Comment: @Sol - A link won't submit any form data. That's why I preceded the suggestion that you use a link with the statement "since you have no other controls". If that was because you cut your example down so much it wouldn't show them, then the statement obviously doesn't apply and you should just pay attention to the first half of the answer instead.

Comment: This is basically what I am trying to do:   print.php?&type="+value+"" Value being landscape or portrait based on the submit button.  So we would have to make a radio button for form elements, but no custom submit buttons?

Comment: @Sol - No. As I said, the submit buttons you have already have a name and a value so the one you use to submit the form will appear in the submitted data already. Just not in the format you originally asked for. And, since you now want it to be named type, not with the name you are now asking for. The PHP you put in the question would find the landscape button if it was used to submit the form.